# Trying to add User in Laravel using Angular but it shows me an error

Tags: json, angular, laravel

I'm trying to use the post method to pass the user to Laravel using a form in HTML so I can store the user in the UserController into the database. I get an `CSRF Token mismatch` error.

I have used this Method to store the user:

```js
addUser(user: User):Observable<User>{
     return this.http.post<User>(this.apiURL+'/addUser',user, httpOptions);
}
```

When I `console.log` the user it works fine. It shows me all attributes when I klick on submit.

I have use this Route in Laravel to store the user:

```php
Route::post('/addUser','UserController@create');
```

In the Controllermethod I used this code:

```php
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $data2 = $request->json()->all(); 
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You called your variable `data2`, and you're using `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel, by default, has `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware enabled for all routes. This is for security (to avoid cross site attacks) and checks for a CSRF token for all requests. But you can set middlewares for route groups such as `web`, `api',`console`.

Try to move `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware from `$middleware` variable to `web` group in `$middlewareGroups` variable in `Http/Kernel.php`. By doing this, you only enable this middleware for `web` routes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it helped, thank you but i guess the way how I store the user in laravel is wrong. It gets me an internal server error because its not type of an array.

Comment: It can be because of you set your variable as `$data2 = $request->json()->all(); ` and call it as `$data['name']`; You need to remove `2`.